# Algorithm for obtaining a sum with minimum number of terms

Tags: algorithm, recursion

The problem statement is following:
Given `N`. We need to find `x1`,`x2`,`..`,`xp` such that `N = x1 + x2 + .. + xp`, p must be minimum(means number of terms in the sum) and we also must be able to get all the numbers from 1 to (N-1) from the sum of the subset of (x1,x2,x3..xp).And numbers in the set might be repeated also.

For example if N=7.

`7 = 1+2+4`
And `6= (2,4)` , `5= (4,1)`, `4 = (4)`,`3=(1,2)` and so on.

Example 2:
`8 = 1+2+4+1`

Example 3:(invalid)
8 = 1+2+5
But we can't get 4 from the subset of (1,2,5).So (1,2,5) is not a valid combination

My approach is if 'N-1'can be written as sum of p terms than 'N' either have p or p+1 terms. But that approach will require to check all possible combinations which sums up to "N-1" and have "p" terms. Can anyone has better solution other than this?

Solution:
Step1:
Assume that we got "K" entries in our set as our answer. Therefore we can obtain 2^K different numbers of sums from these numbers because each entry either will appear or not appear in the sum. And also if the the number is "N", we need to compute the sum for '1' to 'N'. Therefore 
 (2^K -1) = N 
K=log(N+1)
Step2:
After the step1, we know that our answer must include "K" entries but what these entries actual are? Assume that our entries are (a1,a2,a3...ak). So number P can be written as 
P = a1*b1 + a2*b2 + a3*b3....+ ak*bk. Where all b[i] = 0 or 1. Here, we can see P as a decimal representation of binary number (b1 b2 b3  bk), therefore we can take a[i] = 2^(i-1).

Comment: As described your algorithm is not possible for most numbers. For example, for the number 8 it is impossible to construct a set of *unique* numbers such that they add to 8 and can be combined to make every number from 1 to 8. In fact, it's only possible for numbers that are one less than a power of two.

Comment: We can write  8 as 1+2+4+1. Right?

Comment: @Manish - if you're allowed to repeat terms, then the problem reduces to the list x1 = 1. Obviously, we can produce any number be repeated addition of 1...

Comment: @lib - if you list the numbers 1,2,4,8 you have listed 4 unique numbers, of which some subset can be combined to produce 8, and also to produce any number less than 8, so that list is sufficient. Since no smaller set meets both of those criteria, that list is the smallest such list.

Comment: @JonKiparsky, problem is the condition `N = x1 + .. + xp`

Comment: @JonKiparsky: You are right all 1's sum up to that number but this will not be a optimal solution.

Comment: @RiaD - I'm assuming that the condition is some numbers x1,x2...xp such that we can form any number n where n <= N using each term at most once. This is consistent with the problem statement above and it's the only way the problem makes sense.

Comment: @JonKiparsky, I believe that one of conditions is what you said and the other one `N = x1 + x2 + .. + xp`, But I could be wrong.

Comment: Doesn't work as a problem that way - see llb's objection, which is correct if you take that as a condition.

Comment: @JonKiparsky:
But Jon sum of (1,2,4,8) can go beyond 8 also. And as we need to divide "N". The sum must not be greater than N.

Comment: Well, it's your problem, have it your way. In that case, @lib is right and there's only solutions for N where N is 1 less than some pwer of 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take all numbers 1,2,4 ....2^k, N-(1+...+2^k). (The last one only if it doesn't equal to 0)

## Proof

1. First of all, if we only get `k` numbers, we can get maximum `2^k - 1` different sums except 0. So if `N>=2^k`, We need at least `k + 1` numbers. So you can see that if our group of numbers correct it's minimum by size(or one of the minimums)
2. It's easy to see that we can get any number from 0 to `2^(k+1) - 1` using first numbers. What If we need more? We just get last number because it's less than `2^(k + 1)`. And get difference using first elements

Comment: Great..And I am pondering over this from past 1 day..:O

Comment: Could somebody say, is this proof hard too understand?(I do think so) I'd try to rewrite it so.

Comment: I don't understand the proof, but only because I do not understand the question in the first place

Comment: @aaronman:
Do u feel any ambiguity in the question? If so tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Honestly I just don't understand what your asking is there a list involved we have to choose from

Comment: No. You have just given a number N. And u need to find minimum number of elements less that "N" which sums up to N with an additional condition. Which is that we also must be able to find the sum of the numbers from 1 to N-1 from the above numbers

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run out the numbers on this, but you should be very very interested in the fact that you have listed the first three powers of two.

If I were looking for a better solution, that's where I'd start.

Comment: This is not an answer, and if I understand the question correctly it he only listed the first 3 powers of 2 because that is his list not because there is anything special about it

Comment: No, I agree, I didn't give him the answer wrapped up with a purple bow on it. Thought he might enjoy figuring it out - and that hint should certainly have got him there.

Comment: Um, then don't post the answer, put a comment

Comment: @RiaD I must not understand the question than I though he was choosing numbers from a list

Comment: @aaronman Well, in a sense he was. The point of the problem is, there's a reason that those numbers form his list.